Building electron app using quasar on Linux for Windows
Running build with
    sudo quasar build -m electron --target win32

The build is successful, however when starting exe file on Windows machine the error pops up:
Error
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process

Uncaught Exception:
Error:
\\?\C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\e3b61312-6446-4081-be67-d409fb7a26a7.tmp.no...
is not a valid Win32 application.
\\?\C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\e3b61312-6446-4081-be67-d409fb7a26a7.tmp.no...
    at process.func [as dlopen] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:1869)
    at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1326:18)
    at Object.func [as .node] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:2096)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1096:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:937:12)
    at f._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13377)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at load
    (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\appname\resources\app.asar\node_modules:...10)
    at Object.<anonymous>
    (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\appname\resources\app.asar\node_modules:...46)

tried adding
    asar: {
          smartUnpack: true
        },
        asarUnpack: '*.node',

to quasar.conf.js
and
    sudo yarn add cjs-loader --save```

same error.

